# Почему не работает метод save?

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь в shell проверить форму, но в cleaned_date ничего не появляется. Подскажите в чем проблема ?

**shell**

```
>>> d = {'text': 'framework', 'name':'Lena','email':'dudashvili@mail.ru'}
>>> r = ReviewForm(d)                                                     
>>> r.is_bound
True
>>> r.is_valid()
True
>>> r.cleaned_data
{}  
>>>
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from .models import Reviews


            #Форма отзывов
    class ReviewForm(forms.Form):
        text = models.TextField("Сообщение", max_length=5000)
        name = models.CharField("Имя", max_length=100, db_index=True)
        email = models.EmailField()
    
        def save(self):
            new_review = Reviews.objects.create(
            text=self.cleaned_data['text'],
            name=self.cleaned_data['name'],
            email=self.cleaned_data['email']
            )
            return new_review
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

        #Отзывы
class Reviews(models.Model): 
    email = models.EmailField()
    name = models.CharField("Имя", max_length=100, db_index=True)
    text = models.TextField("Сообщение", max_length=5000)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Атрибуты модели и поля формы - это разные типы.
Попробуйте, так:

```
#Форма отзывов
class ReviewForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=5000)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField()
```

Должно сработать.